# What's the difference between the green and red doors?

Tags: atari-50-anniversary-celebration, maze-invaders

In the unreleased arcade game Maze Invaders, (playable in *Atari 50 - The Anniversary Celebration*), when you collect every fruit in a room, doors appear that end the level. The doors can be either green or red.

What's the difference between the green and red doors?

[image: One red door, two green doors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green doors take you to a maze you haven't visited yet while red doors take you to a maze you've already cleared. I confirmed this by checking the bottom-left corner to see which maze doors took me to. Additionally, entering a certain number of green doors (configurable in Dip Switch Settings, 12 by default) will give you bonus points.